# Export from hawt.io's dashboard to databese

Tags: database, monitoring, hawtio, jolokia

How I can export information from hawt.io's dashboard to database in realtime? I want to save history of cpu load and ect, and read they from database later. May be this all wrong way and better write, using jolokia, something specific for my task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hawtio is the visualization of the data, you better extract the data using jolokia yourself to store in the database. Jolokia makes extracting the data easier as you can use REST over HTTP as transport instead of native Java JMX.